# Updating Meteor collection on asynch callback

Tags: meteor

I have a meteor app that uses the node module MQTTClient.

This client sends events whenever something is published to a topic that the client subscribes too.

When the event happens I'd like to update an entry in a collection, but when I do this I get assertion failures and the DB gets corrupted.

```
Assertion failed: (handle->InternalFieldCount() > 0), function Unwrap, file ../src/node_object_wrap.h, line 61.
Exited from signal: SIGABRT
Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

This is what I currently have:

```
...

client.connect(function () {
  console.log('connected to MQTT broker');

  Fiber(function(){
    var allTopics = Topics.find({});
    allTopics.forEach(function(topic){
      console.log('subscribing to ' + topic.name);
      client.subscribe(topic.name);
    });
  }).run();

});

var onPublish = function(topicName, payload, message_id) {
  console.log("New message: " + topicName + ":" + payload);
  Topics.insert({name: payload, value: payload});
};

var wrappedOnPublish = Meteor.bindEnvironment(onPublish, function(e){
  var message = "Something went wrong! " +
                "Everything is broken! " + 
                "Your life is ruined!";

  console.log(message, e.stack);
});

client.on('publish', wrappedOnPublish);
```

I have also tried to handle the callback by wrapping it in a Fiber(..).run() but the exact same error occur.